# Subfig's ragged-right caption with hyphenated word breaks unaesthetically

Tags: captions, line-breaking, subfloats, hyphenation

## Minimal working example

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[]{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \captionsetup[subfigure]{format=hang,singlelinecheck=false,justification=raggedright}
        \subfloat[4-Hy\-droxy\-ben\-zo\-ic acid]{
                \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{4hba_600dpi.png}
        }
        \hfill
        \subfloat[Hy\-droxy\-ben\-zo\-ic acid]{
                \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{4hba_600dpi.png}
        }
        \hfill
        \subfloat[Hydroxybenzoic acid]{
                \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{4hba_600dpi.png}
        }

        \subfloat[Hydroxybenzoic acid]{
                \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{4hba_600dpi.png}
        }
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
        \captionsetup[subfigure]{format=hang,singlelinecheck=false,justification=}
        \subfloat[4-Hy\-droxy\-ben\-zo\-ic acid]{
                \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{4hba_600dpi.png}
        }
        \hfill
        \subfloat[Hy\-droxy\-ben\-zo\-ic acid]{
                \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{4hba_600dpi.png}
        }
        \hfill
        \subfloat[Hydroxybenzoic acid]{
                \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{4hba_600dpi.png}
        }

        \subfloat[Hydroxybenzoic acid]{
                \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{4hba_600dpi.png}
        }
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

## Reference rendering

[image: Hyphenation hints/soft hyphens have an influence on line-breaking when justification=raggedright is used]

## Description

When the justification 'raggedright' is used and the caption must be hyphenated another break is introduced at the next space. Non-breaking spaces can prevent this, but are a poor solution. The workaround used here is resetting justification to the default value. At least, I assume it's what I'm doing in the second figure. The document was compiled using `xelatex`.

## Question(s)

Am I doing anything wrong? Is this a bug? Am I missing a setting? How can I have raggedright justification and proper line-breaking of hyphenated words in subfig captions?

Most likely not duplicates or related: [Preventing hyphenation of specific short, repeated, hyphenated words](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139201/preventing-hyphenation-of-specific-short-repeated-hyphenated-words), [Hyphenation in listings captions doesn't work correctly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173767/hyphenation-in-listings-captions-doesnt-work-correctly), [Prevent wrapping of subfloat captions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7929/prevent-wrapping-of-subfloat-captions), [Figure caption has line break problems when using subfig](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249778/figure-caption-has-line-break-problems-when-using-subfig)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `justification=RaggedRight` (it might require two LaTeX runs). Be careful with end-of-lines.

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{report}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{format=hang,singlelinecheck=false,justification=RaggedRight}

\subfloat[4-Hy\-droxy\-ben\-zo\-ic acid]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{4hba_600dpi.png}%
}\hfill
\subfloat[Hy\-droxy\-ben\-zo\-ic acid]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{4hba_600dpi.png}%
}\hfill
\subfloat[Hydroxybenzoic acid]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{4hba_600dpi.png}%
}

\subfloat[Hydroxybenzoic acid]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{4hba_600dpi.png}%
}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]